# New Light Fixture - wiring does not match

Tags: wiring

We removed a light fixture in the dining room that was installed when we built the house in October 2001.  However; we failed to take a picture of the connections.  The wires from the ceiling are 2 white, 2 black, 1 red, and copper.  The new light fixture has 2 black and a copper.  The light switch is three switches - one to an outdoor outlet, one to an outdoor light, and one to the light over the dining room table which has a dimmer.  Unsure how to connect the new fixture wires to the existing wires.[image]

Comment: instead of using words to describe the function of two unrelated switches, use the words to describe the connections to the related switch

Comment: Were all 6 of those wires connected to the old lamp, or were some only connected to each other?